# grails corrupted lang parameter

Tags: grails, locale

We know that passing the lang parameter in the URL changes the locale of the grails application

```
/url?lang=de
```

In the code I can get the locale by RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request), which returns the locale set in the ParamsAwareLocaleChangeInterceptor (part of grails source), using the lang parameter.

If a script or corrupted string is passed as value to the lang parameter, then the same crap gets set as locale.

```
/url?lang=>"'><script>alert(167) </script>&=>"'><script>alert(167)</script>
```

with this request, the Content-language in the http header is set to the script= value of lang parameter. After this RCU.getLocale() returns this malicious script which messes up the content of my site, as a lot of content is decided based on locale. Is the a way to get around this problem (sanitize the lang before setting the locale) or is this a grails bug?

Also, can I restrict what is being passed in lang? For ex: if only 'en' and 'de' are supported on the site, the passing /url?lang=es messes up the content. is there a way I can restrict the value of lang parameter to only 'en' and 'de', may be in a filter or something, before the change of locale happens in the grails interceptor?

Comment: That's probably a bug. You might be able to use [some of the code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819768/grails-language-prefix-in-url-mappings)
 to work around it.

Comment: Maybe you want to set the locale from a controller rather that passing a `/url?lang`. Use the `setLocale` code from nate_weldon inside an action and just link to that action in your language selector.

Comment: why doesnt grails provide check for garbage? then the feature where lang can be used to change locale is totally useless

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 possible options.

1) To restrict the lang you could set the locale in a Filter upon each request. But this you are resetting every time on a reload.

```
def filters = {

    before = {
        def locale = new Locale("sv","SV")
        RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale)                  
    }

 }
```

2) You could delete all message properties files leaving only the  messages.properties files. So the system will always default to this property file.

3) you could setup a LocaleResolver in your config/spring/resources.groovy to set the default locale.

Comment: I dont want to set the default locale, coz English is already the default. I want to restrict it to 2 locales, en and de

Comment: the filter can work both ways. This one was just a simple one to always set the default. You can use the filter to catch the garbage and then set the correct one

Comment: used filter to remove the crap and setLocale to the right value. But when inside the controller RCU.getLocale still returns the same crap. i am thinking this is because the Content-language in the http request header is corrupted

Comment: The setLocale did not work.. so I ended up redirecting the page to the same url with the right locale in the lang parameter