# Grails Language in URL as subdirectory, map to default language if no parameter

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am trying to set the language parameter in the URL Mappings in grails. 
The idea is that the grails application should allow internationalization based on a language parameter embedded in the URL. 
Examples:

```
/profile // Map to default /en/profile
/it/profile
/sq/profile
```

With the default URL Mapping one can map to each language

```
"/$lang/profile"{
..
}
```

My problem is to use a default language (en) if no $lang parameter is passed in the URL. (so /profile can work as well).

I attempted to add a Filter in grails as well to check if lang.params is null, but that did not work as expected.

```
class LanguageFilters {
    def filters = {
        amendLangParameter(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if( params.lang == null) {
                    println "condition met"
                    redirect( controller: params.controller, action: params.action, params:[ "lang": request.locale.language.toString() ] + params )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819768/grails-language-prefix-in-url-mappings?answertab=active#tab-top) does not help with the issue as tomcat throws a

```
HTTP Status 404 - /profile
type Status report
message /profile
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: "did not work as expected" ... as in, suddenly there were spiders everywhere?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith You are right, adding some more info to the ticket. I was not sure that the filter was the best way though